# Hide json data in from the browser which are getting in android app

Tags: php, android, json, browser

I am pulling JSON values from the browser in my android app, but when I browse php files in the browser, the JSON data is displayed. My question is this: How can I hide the JSON data from the browser for security reasons?

Comment: That is true, You get data follow POST method. On server, You check isset($_POST) and return data.

Answer (score 1):

hi you can do one thing

when you want to fetch data from php , php must fetch data if the request sent by POST method , and contain parameter to check , for more explain

in php file

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['checked'] && $_POST['checked']=="password")
{

echo json_encode($json);

}

?>
```

now from android , when you send http request select post method , and add parameter checked="password"

Comment: +1 thats the only way to do it,  I would call it `api_key` or something instead of `checked`.

Comment: you can improve this idea to be more secure by using https , with auth-key.

Comment: most welcome , please mark my answer , to close this question .